# What time format does IIS record its logs? Where do I find the setting?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7.5

Does IIS log entries in its logs in GMT or UTC time? Where can I find the setting? The server I am running is a Windows 2008 R2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, according to the Interwebz, GMT and UTC are pretty much the same thing, except one adds in leap seconds to make the calendar more accurate.

The default time for IIS logs is in UTC.

On the IIS Manager main page, you can click 'Logging' and it gives you the option to save logs in your local time format (whatever that may be).

Sorry if this is vague, but those are the only answers I could find. I will look around a bit more.

[IIS Log Files: Configuration Reference](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/sites/site/logFile)

Comment: Thanks. Which one adds leap seconds?

Answer (score 1):

Dragging up an old post here, but thought I would clarify for anyone who comes across this in the future.

The setting that cutrightjim refers to:

> On the IIS Manager main page, you can click 'Logging' and it gives you the option to save logs in your local time format (whatever that may be).

Actually only changes the timezone used to **name and rollover the file from one day to the next**

As far as I can see on all my IIS implementations (25 Production Servers running nearly 200 sites for the SaaS product the company I work for sells), the actual log entry is **still in UTC**

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Timestamps on the log entries depends on the log format you select, per https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3368766f-2832-4949-a746-2276a7f22f11/iis-time-zone?forum=iissetup

Had me stumped for years.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1211776)